# Create a non legacy Event

Tags: social-tables

When I use the legacy API call to create an event all works as expected except it is displayed in the Web UI with a 'View Diagrams' and 'View Guest Lists' buttons.

After creating an event using the web app it just displays a 'View Event' button and postfixes the description with '[V2]' The display url is of the form: https://app.socialtables.com/?event=435008 which seems to be using the legacy_id of the event.

I need to be able to create an event that matches the behavior of the Web App.
How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

The legacy API is intended to create Legacy Events, so that is working as it should.  We are in transition from our legacy to 4.0 apis so the following will solution will  work today with minimal changes to your code: setting venue_mapper_version as 3 in the legacy API call.

`{
    ...
    "venue_mapper_version": 3
}`

To ensure future-proof functionality you should also consider using our /4.0/events routes as they will be the answer going forward. https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#/Events

Comment: I do not see a documented 4.0 API call to create an event. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey there, sorry for some reason it was marked internal.

It's there now: https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Events/post_4_0_events